# Create hyper links using PHP and webform

Tags: php, javascript, html

Every week I manually create links using copy and paste techniques. I'm thinking I'm nuts and can find a way to do this quicker and faster.

A123456
B34567
d928333
s121233

These numbers need to be added to a hyperlink like so

`hxxp://website.com/1/go/A123456/1`
`hxxp://website.com/1/go/B34567/1`
`hxxp://website.com/1/go/d928333/1`

And be HYPERLINKS ( to test the url to make sure its right).

I'm thinking a small web form for me to enter the list of numbers and a submit button. After submitting the page displays all the hyperlinks as clickable html

`http://website.com/1/go/A123456/1`
`http://website.com/1/go/B34567/1`
`http://website.com/1/go/d928333/1`

Can someone show me some base code to get this working

Danke
-om

Comment: can you post code you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to start with something like

```
<?php
foreach(explode(' ', $_POST['inputName']) as $num) {
    $printable = htmlspecialchars($num, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    echo '<a href="http://website.com/1/go/', $printable, '/1">', $printable, '</a> ';
}
```

Comment: wumm - no database. php form with submit button and refreshes the page with links. 

@TML - thanks. Umm is there a way to submit the $printable?

Comment: What do you mean "submit the $printable"? See http://codepad.viper-7.com/aj3Jmr to see this code in action.

Comment: thanks. what i mean is I need to paste a list of codes into a webform which then spits out the full html URL as a hyperlink. This is close however. Each week the codes are different.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/WdPqA1 this is fine for the display. How do i get the numbers into this ^^ I guess to POST to it?

Comment: You make a form with the action set to this PHP file, and a single input named "inputName", and then paste the codes into the form and submit it; it will generate the output.

Comment: ok so this will be empty: $_POST['inputName'] = '';